# Map command with prefix in Vim

Tags: vim

Some Vim commands could have expression as prefix, like `100j` or `20k`, how to map the entire command? I want to call a Vim function before invoking the given command.

EDIT: I want to preserve the previous input number for j/k as repeat times, the calling function might be unrelated. For example, I want to do some bookkeeping before every j or k command, but I don't want to break the number prefix.

Comment: can you make an example? your vim function returns a number, and you want to use that number with for example, j, k ...?

Comment: how did you save the count(ie 100,20) of j/k? create a command with function to do j/k with count, or  wrap j/k in a function?

Comment: @Kent I have no idea about how to save it (the called function doesn't save anything), I want to save this value for j/k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every problem can be solved by adding another layer of indirection
>   except the problem of having too many layers of indirection
>     - Misquote of David Wheeler and Kevlin Henney

So how are we going to solve this? Add a layer of **indirection**!

One way to do this by is using a map expression which calls a function that does the "book keeping" and returns the command back.

```
let s:bookkeeping = {}
function! s:bookkeeping(count, cmd)
  let s:bookkeeping[a:cmd] = get(s:bookkeeping, a:cmd, 0) + a:count
  return a:cmd
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> j <SID>bookkeeping(v:count1, 'j')
```

Personally I think their is little to gain from gathering data on such commands as their is no context however it is probably good to see how to do an map expression. See `:h :map-<expr>` for more information.

Comment: The nnoremap mentioned v:count1 but not defined it anywhere, is this a typo? Besides, how is the count applied to cmd (j) here?

Comment: All variables prefixed with `v:` are vim variables which always exists. See `:h v:`. We do not need to append a count to `j` as it will read `v:count1` internally.

Comment: Why using v:count1 here? Does it get the prefix number before invoking the following navigation command?

Comment: The count given for the last Normal mode command.  Can be used to get the count before a mapping. Please see `:h v:count`